# How do I see the how the JSON object is formatted?

Tags: json

I have an application which is sending me JSON object. Now I want to see how this json data structure in javascript alert something like this. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't even develop in Chrome/firefox ? I would look at changing this, it would be like coding with one hand tied behind your back.  My preferred method is using Chrome dev toolbar, but here are some other ways.

You can debug using a browser based debugger, for [ie](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) .

You could use the [JSON.stringifiy](http://www.json.org/js.html) and `alert` the output,the code is [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

And there are these viewers as well http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and [jollydroll](http://www.jollydroll.com/tools/json)

And finally you can loop through the different object properties like so :

```
 for(var propertyName in yourJSON){
     //will loop through the different elements in your json 
     alert(yourJSON[propertyName]); //will output the valueof each element
     alert(propertyName); //will output name of each element
}
```

Comment: You must be clairvoyant of his needs haha. +1 for the viewer apps (though hopefully most people aren't in the IE-only situation).

Comment: somehow JSON.stringify is not working for me. And if I just use the alert(jsonObj) then it display like [object object]

Comment: have you downloaded and included json2.js ?

Comment: Ohh, now I understand why I don't see the stringify function. Let me try this now.

Comment: Earlier I try something like this jsonData.toString()/jsonData.toHtml(), none of them worked

Comment: Great!!! After importing json2.js, I can not see the json data structures. Thanks to all for their great and quick response. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @jsfan you can accept one of the answers if you are happy with the solution.

Comment: I use your solution and it worked for me. Thanks again for your great support

Answer (score 1):

You could throw the JSON into Firebug's console (or Chrome's developer console?) and get a pretty-print view of it.

Comment: Thanks McStretch for you such a quick reply. But the problem is our application only support IE 6/7/8. So I cannot use the Firebug or developer console.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you can provide me an alternative. I tried to see in the IEDeveloper toolbar but no success.

Comment: I sympathize with you :P. I would take a look at the viewers that NimChimpsky mentions then.

Comment: Great!!! After importing json2.js, I can not see the json data structures. Thanks to all for their great and quick response. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

easiest would be to use alert(json) or console.log(json) - available with development tools

Comment: just alerting the json will not show contents you need to stringify first.

Comment: basically json is a string which can be parsed, so no stringify needed, but rather parse, but only for console as alert would show "[Object object]" after parse

Comment: console.log(jsonObj); displaying like this

Comment: exactly, you need to stringify

Comment: Great!!! After importing json2.js, I can not see the json data structures. Thanks to all for their great and quick response. I really appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

In IE8, Tools->Developer Tools (F12), Script.

Set a breakpoint and examine the JSON result in Locals? It won't be 'structured', but should be readable if it's not huge

Comment: Great!!! After importing json2.js, I can now see the json data structures. Thanks to all for their great and quick response. I really appreciate your time